# SQL cloning and converting a date column

Tags: sql, postgresql

(postgreSQL database)

I have a date column that appears to be in the format of 'yyyy-mm-dd' firstly I'd like to convert that said column to 'yyyymm'.

After that I'd like to clone that column to another column within the same table which I'd call "year" and I'd need to have that in the format of 'yyyy' only.

I'm yet to find a simple solution that would apply to my case and that's basic enough, as I'm new to SQL in general.

In the end I'd like the columns to be like this (excluding the other existing columns)

```
   date /*already exists*/  year /*need to create*/
   201501                   2015
   201501                   2015
   201502                   2015
   201606                   2016
```

Cheers

Comment: Why are you storing dates in a varchar (or integer) column? Why not use a real `date` data type? If you have that, you can _display_ the date in any format you like

Comment: The date column is a 'date' datatype right now, I just wasn't sure of how to convert then clone into another column but only take the year portion, thanks.

Comment: "*appears to be*" is correct, the postgresql date column is of type integer (on the disk) , but for presentation it looks like years months and days.

Comment: Why do you want to duplicate that information? You can easily access all parts of a `date` column without the need to "clone" that information into a different column. What is the underlying problem you are trying to solve with that?

Comment: It's something that I'm being asked to do as a separate column, the reason why is beyond me, my manager was a software engineer with good knowledge so I'll just follow orders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this help you?

This is using the built in date formatting in the TO_CHAR function. I'm not completely at home with postgresql tho', so some tweaking might need to be done.

```
UPDATE
    TABLENAME
SET
    year = TO_CHAR(date, 'YYYY'),
    date = TO_CHAR(date, 'YYYYMM');
```

If the column "year" does not already exist, you will have to create it with a `ALTER TABLE` statement first

```
ALTER TABLE [table_name] ADD COLUMN [column_name] [data_type] {collation} {column_contstraint};
```

I would recommend checking the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-altertable.html) for the correct usage.

EDIT: If you are worrying about the time it would take to update all rows (I saw you commented on another answer that you had around 2 million records), then I suggest reading [this post](https://blog.codacy.com/how-to-update-large-tables-in-postgresql-e9aecd197fb7#.3s17564xg).

It explains that it might be quicker to create the table from scratch with the data instead of updating each and every row.

Comment: This won't create my column, or will it? I haven't created the column itself as I'm not sure how to set the formatting of the column "year", cheers. Also my column has over 2 million rows, I heard using the update/set method is quite resource demanding at that level, is this true?

Comment: Oh, my bad then. Well you would have to first create the column with a
`ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN ...` command that you would run once, then you can apply `UPDATE` statement above. I'm editing my answer with this.

Comment: @MG97 I've added some to my answer, including a link to "how to go about" updating data when the table is really big.

Comment: I would've made the table from scratch but a  lot of work has gone into modifying it already, so I'd rather not restart again.

Comment: @MG97 You could just go ahead and use the `UPDATE`-statement method, which will take some time (a lot of records to execute on). Or you could go about and using the temporary table method described in the link I posted (without needing to drop the old table). Your call. However, whichever method you end up using, try make sure that database traffic is at a minimum when doing it, since you will be putting quite some load on the DB-engine during the execution.

Comment: The TO_CHAR or TO_DATE don't seem to be functions of postgreSQL, I'm running a query currently where I created a column with datatype of 'date' and now I'm running a `UPDATE mytable SET date=year;` this I'm hoping will give me the results then I would just need to change the formatting.

Comment: @MG97 Weird that TO_CHAR would not be a postgreSQL function, since it is referenced in [this documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-formatting.html). But maybe you're running a version where it's not implemented.

Comment: Thank you for your help, in the end I ended up ruining my table however now I rebuilt it and sorted it, thank you for the resource links, they were helpful in resolving this for me.

Answer (score 2):

To add the new column, run

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD year character varying(4);
```

That should finish quickly if there are no locks on the table.

To modify the data, run

```
UPDATE mytable
SET date = substr(date, 1, 4) || substr(date, 6, 2),
    year = substr(date, 1, 4);
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, will this also create my date column?

Comment: Also my column has over 2 million rows, I heard using the update/set method is quite resource demanding at that level, is this true?

Comment: I have added instructions how to create a column. Two million rows is not so many, so don't worry. Of course this is resource consuming, since it rewrites the whole table, but that is unavoidable if you want to modify all rows.

Comment: Sorry can you explain the SET part of the query, I always thought || means 'or' but I can't get my head around it in this case, thanks.

Comment: ALTER TABLE mytable ADD "year" character varying(4) NOT NULL; doesn't seem to run as the table initially has null values

Comment: @MG97 In SQL, || means "concatenate", and is used to merge two strings into one.

Comment: I have removed the `NOT NULL`, you were right about that. You'd have to add that later. The operator `||` is the string concatenation operator in SQL.

Comment: I was unable to run it this way, I'm hoping I can do the following then change the formatting - I created a column with datatype of 'date' and now I'm running a `UPDATE mytable SET date=year;` this I'm hoping will give me the results then I would just need to change the formatting, one to show the yyyymm and one to show yyyy only. Thansk though, this clarified some things for me