# Converting from VARCHAR to DATE

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a db where I have converted 2 date columns to varchar for the purpose of getting 1 column substringed into another. However, now I don't seem to be able to convert the datatype when I try to use:

```
 ALTER TABLE datacomplete
 ALTER COLUMN yearmonth TYPE DATE; /*Can't find a way to specify a format*/
```

It throws this error:

> ERROR: column "yearmonth" cannot be cast automatically to type date
>   Hint: You might need to specify "USING yearmonth::date".

I'm not sure how to use that command at all, could anyone potentially assist?

My first column is in the format of `yyyy-mm-dd`, however I'd like it to be `yyyymm` only, but I'm guessing this is easier once I convert the datatype to date and I can somehow switch formats.

The second column only shows the year so I need to convert it to date as format '`yyyy`'.

UPDATE: The first one was solved, now I need to convert the second to 'yyyy'

```
    ALTER TABLE pscomplete_1 ALTER COLUMN "year" TYPE DATE USING "year"::date;
```

It throws this error

> 15:12:51  [ALTER - 0 rows, 1.062 secs]  [Code: 0, SQL State: 22007]  ERROR: >invalid input syntax for type date: "2016"
>   ... 1 statement(s) executed, 0 rows affected, exec/fetch time: 1.062/0.000 sec  >[0 successful, 1 errors]

Comment: What is your question? The command `ALTER TABLE datacomplete ALTER COLUMN yearmonth TYPE DATE USING yearmonth::date;` should work if yearmonth contains well-formed dates ...

Comment: @FabianPijcke Thank you, I tried loads of variations, just didn't think about just sticking it on the end like that, so the first one is done, now I only need to do the second one

Comment: Just change the USING part by USING (year || '-01-01')::date ;-)

Comment: Works! But any way to stop it from displaying as '2016-01-01' because when I try to query it as `SELECT * FROM pscomplete_1
WHERE "year"='2015';` it says invalid input syntax. :(

Comment: Based on this and on [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41589085/sql-cloning-and-converting-a-date-column) I think something somewhere went horribly wrong. You completely misunderstood what an RBDMS is used for. Your original date column was more than enough to produce results in both `yyyymm` and `yyyy` formats. Maybe if you could describe the original problem we could actually help you solve it.

Comment: @pozs It's all solved now thanks, I'm not sure myself why my manager wanted 2, but I had to stick to a strict format used previously, and even asked him, I'll ask him after why this was needed anyway to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The USING keyword allows you to give the translation function to PostgreSQL.

For your first column it is easy for you already have a correct DATE format:

```
ALTER TABLE datacomplete ALTER COLUMN yearmonth TYPE DATE USING yearmonth::DATE;
```

For your second column it is unclear for PostgreSQL which exact date you want. Let's say we want the first of January of the given year:

```
ALTER TABLE datacomplete ALTER COLUMN year TYPE DATE USING (year || '-01-01')::DATE;
```

Comment: Works! But any way to stop it from displaying as '2016-01-01' because when I try to query it as SELECT * FROM pscomplete_1 WHERE "year"='2015'; it says invalid input syntax. :(

Comment: This is because the DATE type in PostgreSQL can only store complete dates. If you want to store a year, you should use the INT type. To convert back just use extract(year from year).

Comment: Okay, that worked anyway, I'm speaking to my manager and the date thing should be fine if that's how it ouputs it in postgresql, thank you for your help sir.

Answer (score 0):

I understood you were starting from a VARCHAR column in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD'.
So I'll do the same.

And you want a column in the date format, and you want a yearmonth in all-digits format.

If I'm not forced to use leading zeroes in an all-digits column, I prefer INT to string columns.

And I prefer to make the same derivation only once if I can do that.

This is why I use a WITH clause (global table expression) to cast the varchar to date, and then I use the resulting date for the DATE_PART() function I use to create the yearmonth column. I have seen very often that date arithmetics are safer and often faster than subtring-ing the date literal (remember, the Americans format dates differently from the Europeans, there are different formats within Europe, and also in Asia, and not all like the ISO date format). So I derive yearmonth as the year multiplied by 100, plus the month, and as DATE_PART() returns a float, I cast the whole expression to INT.

So here goes:

```
WITH foo(varchar_dt) AS (
          SELECT '2017-01-11'
UNION ALL SELECT '2016-12-11'
UNION ALL SELECT '2016-11-11'
UNION ALL SELECT '2016-10-11'
)
,    foo_with_date AS (
SELECT
  varchar_dt
, CAST(varchar_dt AS DATE) AS the_date
FROM foo
)
SELECT
  varchar_dt
, the_date
, CAST(DATE_PART('year',the_date)*100 + DATE_PART('month',the_date) AS INT) AS yearmonth
FROM foo_with_date
;    

varchar_dt|the_date  |yearmonth
2017-01-11|2017-01-11|  201,701
2016-12-11|2016-12-11|  201,612
2016-11-11|2016-11-11|  201,611
2016-10-11|2016-10-11|  201,610
```

I can't help myself - I find this much cleaner, and filtering by yearmonth would become filtering by an integer, which is always at least a little bit faster than strings.

Happy playing

Marco the Sane